# Is a good practice aliasing php native functions?

Tags: php, psr-2

would help PSR naming conventions. Would it be a good practice?

Example:

```
use function array_keys as getArrayKeys;
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this aliasing?

Comment: @u_mulder function naming convention. I think some php function name looks quite old as they're from php 4

Answer (score 4):

It sounds as a bad practice in my opinion.
For the current project/page no harm is really done but in the long run you may/will forget what the real functions names are.
On the next project you will try `getArrayKeys` and it won't work.

Comment: Not to mention, if someone else takes over your code later, they will struggle to understand it if you use these aliases a lot.